# Framebuffer texture transparency without fragment rejection?

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

I'd like to be able to render to a framebuffer and then render that texture to the standard opengl buffer. My problem is that when I don't use fragment rejection, the framebuffers color is black but I would like for it to be transparent.

Here's without fragment rejection (checking for color(0.0,0.0,0.0) ):

[image]

and here is with fragment rejection, but now any texture with black on it will also be transparent. I'd like only the base framebuffer texture to be transparent. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: What about using the alpha channel? Reject when alpha=0 instead of when color=black.

Comment: Ok that worked great, write that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Alpha testing is a form of fragment rejection, just as depth or stencil testing is. The only difference is it is no longer a discrete part of the pipeline, you have to do it in a shader these days. What you seem to be referring to in actuality is color-key transparency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what the alpha channel is usually used for. Initialize the alpha value of the texture to 0 and then you can either reject the fragments when alpha=0 or else use alpha blending (or both).